# HAProxy - Rewriting URL's transparently

Tags: configuration, url-rewriting, acl, haproxy

I need to implement an URL rewriting action for a project. This has to be done with HAProxy-1.5 because it is implemented on a PfSense firewall and later versions are not available to this point.

I have the following URLS:
update.domain.com
repository.domain.com
which both point to the same backend server1. The challenge now is to move the document root:
- update.domain.com >> /some/path/repo1.
- repository.domian.com >> /some/path/repo2

Not only is the document root moved but due to a earlier implementation with TMG servers links exists that point to files like this:
update.domain.com/file1.txt

I have tried to work with http-request set-path and some ACL's on the frontend but unfortuanly this function is available with versions > haproxy-1.6

```
frontend www
 bind *:80 
 acl    update_url  hdr_beg(host) -m beg update.domain.com 
 acl    update_root path_beg /some/path/repo1/
 http-request set-header /some/path/repo1/%[path] if !update_root update_url    
 use_backend testServer if update_root update_url
 default_backend testServer
```

Links to files such as update.domain.com/file1.txt cant be changed. Keeping TMG is not a solution. How can i get this working with Haproxy-1.5?

Answer (score 1):

For HAProxy 1.5, you can use [reqrep](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-reqrep), which will replace the request line (and any header lines) with what you specify in your regex, e.g something like:

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /some/path/repo1/(.*) \1\ /some/path/repo2\2
```

A more detailed explanation of how to use `reqrep` can be found [here](https://github.com/kamleshchandnani/haproxy/blob/master/haproxy-reqrep.md).